# Generate LaTeX font size \footnotesize of barplot in saved PDF file

Tags: r, latex, sweave

Code produces too small font size:

```
pdf("fileName.pdf", width=100, height=50)
par(mai=c(2, 1, 1, 1), lwd=2)
barplot(as.numeric(c(2, 4, 1, 6)), col = c("lightblue"),
        main="Bar plot",
        names.arg=c("This is bar 1...1","This is bar 1...2",
                    "This is bar 1...3","This is bar 1...4"),
        xpd=TRUE, las=2, lwd=2, 
        cex.axis=9, cex.names=9, cex.main=9)
dev.off()
```

Code produces too large font size:

```
pdf("fileName.pdf", width=100, height=50)
par(mai=c(2, 1, 1, 1), lwd=2)
barplot(as.numeric(c(2, 4, 1, 6)), col = c("lightblue"),
        main="Bar plot",
        names.arg=c("This is bar 1...1","This is bar 1...2",
                    "This is bar 1...3","This is bar 1...4"),
        xpd=TRUE, las=2, lwd=2, 
        cex.axis=18, cex.names=18, cex.main=18)
dev.off()
```

Question:
How to get the same font size as document font which is \footnotesize.

To get LaTeX \footnotesize `cex`s has to be 13, 14, or 15. Any ideas how to get the right value? Is it computable?

Comment: Can a comparison be done after creating PDF-file? I mean checking the PDF file: read and compute the sizes of text and of the created graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One "bad" solution is to compare the font sizes in the PDF file by loading the PDF and measure the size (the hight) of a "0" created with {\footnotesize{0}} and a "0" in the bar plot at point (0,0) with an ruler or triangle directly on display (screen).

`cex` has then various valous for different bar plots (with different widths and heights). At my case it was `cex=9`.

A computational way can maybe be done the same by loading the pdf as image (e.g. PNG) and select computationally the areas of manually created text and bar plots to search in each areas for one "0" and compare the two zeros by each other.

If you have any idea how to do it effectively and with a bunch of code, please reply and give your idea/s!